# Why does a program compile despite an apparent lifetime mismatch?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Given the following Rust program:

```
struct Value<'v>(&'v ());
struct Container {}

impl Container {
    fn get<'v>(&'v self) -> Value<'v> {
        todo!()
    }
    
    fn set<'v>(&'v self, x: Value<'v>) {
        todo!()
    }
}

fn convert<'v1, 'v2>(x: &'v1 Container, env: &'v2 Container) {
    let root: Value<'v2> = env.get();
    x.set(root);
}
```

I would expect `convert` to be a compile time error as `Value<'v2>` gets passed to `x.set()` which requires a value of type `Value<'v1>` - but it successfully compiles. There is no subtyping relationship between `'v1` and `'v2`. How has Rust inferred satisfying lifetimes?

Comment: There's no way you can implement `get` and `set` to make `convert` unsound. Try it.

Comment: @trentcl not without using unsafe. But in the case I'm writing, I am using unsafe, but "safely", and it is the case that convert is unsound (but I appreciate that's just reflecting that my unsafe isn't quite safe enough).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler is always allowed to re-borrow with a shorter lifetime.

In this case, what happens in:

```
fn convert<'v1, 'v2>(x: &'v1 Container, env: &'v2 Container) {
    let root: Value<'v2> = env.get();
    x.set(root);
}
```

Is that the compiler reborrows `x` (aka `(&*x)`) with a lifetime `'v3`, shorter than `'v2`, which is allowed due to the (inferred) variance of `Value<'v>` (which matches `&'v T`).

---

It is possible to change the inferred variance of `Value<'v>` by changing the inner value:

- `&'v ()` (the current) is **covariant**.
- `Cell<&'v ()>` is **invariant**.
- `fn (&'v ()) -> ()` is **contravariant**, the inverse of *covariant*.

Using an *invariant* `Value<'v>` prevents unifying the lifetime with a fresh one, while using a *contravariant* `Value<'v>` only allows unifying the lifetime with a *greater* one.

Comment: Thanks! And to stop the variance, I defined Value as `Cell<&'v ()>` which then causes a compile-time mismatch.

Comment: I meant contra, so I'll sneakily remove my comment and integrate it in the answer... with the fix.